# Python recursive yield asymptotic runtime

Tags: python, recursion, generator, time-complexity

I'm writing a recursive generator function that basically looks like this:

```
def f(n):
  if n > 0:
    for i in f(n-1):
      yield i
  yield n
```

This has runtime O(n^2). Sadly, the python3 (3.3) version

```
def f(n):
  if n > 0:
    yield from f(n-1)
  yield n
```

suffers the same problem. Clearly, this iteration should only take O(n) time. Any ideas?

Comment: The Python 3 version is basically the same as the Python 2 version, it's just using different syntax. `yield from f(n-1)` is just hiding that inner for loop that has to be explicitly typed in Python 2. The Python 3 version might be slightly faster because `yield from` allows some optimizations under the covers to speed up the iteration, but it's still the same big-O.

Comment: Is it expected that `list(f(5)) == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe has been [considered in PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#optimisations) and it noted that optimization of the recursive `yield from` such as you suggest could be performed by a Python language implementation.

> Using a specialised syntax opens up possibilities for optimisation when there is a long chain of generators. Such chains can arise, for instance, when recursively traversing a tree structure. The overhead of passing **next**() calls and yielded values down and up the chain can cause what ought to be an O(n) operation to become, in the worst case, O(n**2).

Apparently, CPython 3 cannot optimize this, and the `yield from` becomes just a syntactic sugar for the explicit loop you have in your Python 2.7 code.